# Clearing emails after sending in angular

Tags: angularjs, email

I'm trying to figure out how I can clear the emails in the list. I've managed to create a function where I can remove emails one by one. But I can't seem to find a way on how to clear them all after sending clicking the send invite button.

I'm working on project using angular.js and below is a sample of the code that is a work in progress

```
<div class="content referral-sender-page">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main" ng-controller="ReferralDispatchController">
      <h1 class="h large">Send Invites</h1>
      <!-- TODO: Explanatory text -->
      <div>
      <section class="grid__item bp-md-one-third">
        <h5 class="h medium gray">To</h5>
        <span ng-repeat="e in emails" class="h small email-list">
            <span remove-on-click ng-click="removeEmail(e)" class="email-item">{{ e }} <small class="close">X</small></span>
        </span>
        <div class="col-2">
          <input class="input" type="email"
                 ng-model="email"
                 placeholder="Email">
          <a ng-click="addEmail()" class="button pads primary" >+</a>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="grid__item bp-md-two-thirds">
        <h5 class="h medium gray">Message</h5>
        <p>Write a message to send to your homies with your invite</p>
        <textarea class="text-input" ng-model="message" rows="5">
          This is awesome and you should try it!
        </textarea>
      </section>
      </div>
      <div class="space--bottom one-whole">
        <a ng-click="sendReferral()" class="button pads primary">Send Email Invite</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
var ctrls = angular.module('elstudio.controllers.site');

//Removes Element only
// ctrls.directive('removeOnClick', function() {
//     return {
//         link: function(scope, elt, attrs) {
//             scope.removeEmail = function() {
//                 elt.remove();
//             };
//         }
//     }
// });


ctrls.controller('ReferralDispatchController', function ($scope, UserService,
                                                         ReferralService) {

    $scope.emails = [];
    $scope.message = '';



    $scope.removeEmail = function(e) {
        var index = $scope.emails.indexOf(e);
        $scope.emails.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.addEmail = function() {

        if (!$scope.email) {
            $scope.$emit('notify', { message: 'Please provide a valid email address' });
            return;
        }
        // If email already in list, ignore
        // FIXME: Provide feedback
        if ($scope.emails.indexOf($scope.email) != -1) {
            $scope.email = '';
            return;
        }

        $scope.emails.push($scope.email);
        $scope.email = '';
    };

    $scope.sendReferral = function() {
        if (!$scope.loginUser) {
            $scope.$emit('notify', { message: 'Please sign up or log in to your Electric account.',
                                     duration: 3000 });
            angular.element('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
            angular.element('.login-toggle').click();
            return;
        }

        if ($scope.email != '') {
            $scope.emails.push($scope.email);
        }

        if (!$scope.emails) {
            $scope.$emit('notify', { message: 'Please provide at least one email address' });
            return;
        }

        var refer = {
            emails: $scope.emails,
            message: $scope.message
        };

        var sendSuccess = function() {
            $scope.$emit('notify', { message: 'An invitation has been sent!',
                                     duration: 4000 });
        };
        var sendFailed = function(error) {
            // Retry?
            $scope.$emit('notify', { message: "Couldn't send invitation",
                                     duration: 4000 });
        };

        ReferralService.email(refer).$promise.then(sendSuccess, sendFailed);
    };


});
```

Comment: kindly add services ReferralService and UserService

Answer (score 2):

Please Use

```
  var refer = {
            emails: angular.copy($scope.emails),
            message:  angular.copy($scope.message)
        };
```

Please view the [detail](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

It will do deep copy. So when we change the value in $scope.emails and $scope.message copied value will not change

also clear the $Scope.email value in the `sendSuccess` function

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.email = []; used to clear the array.

 var sendSuccess = function() {
        $scope.$emit('notify', { message: 'An invitation has been sent!',
                                 duration: 4000 });
     $scope.email = [];
    };
```